# mashape sentiment and R integration

Tags: r, curl, sentiment-analysis

Here is one mashpe sentiment analysis curl code returning json. How to integrate it with R?

curl -X POST --include 'https://community-sentiment.p.mashape.com/text/' \
      -H 'X-Mashape-Key: pVke3AAqHzmsh4xNdsKrPshYHQC1p1H78y0jsn2uwaEPcU1TnF' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
      -H 'Accept: application/json' \
      -d 'txt=Today is  a good day'

Edit: Also how can I add -d 'txt=Today is a good day' part in a variable? say text<-'Today is a good day' and use variable text in r syntax. Apologies in case it is very basic, I am new to R. –  user3548327 just now   edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after removing \ (Which I did long ago, by the way!) and ensuring all syntax is intact, in my R environment I am getting the error with code 6, for above code or ended up in 500 error. As a last resort moved away from system(curl..) syntax and used postForm("http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/text/",txt = "mysentence"). Works for me! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just run it, and parse it with one of the JSON packages:

```
R> res <- system("curl -s ....rest of your query as above...", intern=TRUE)
R> jsonlite::fromJSON(res[-(1:9)])
$result
$result$confidence
[1] "96.7434"

$result$sentiment
[1] "Positive"


R>
```

I added a `-s` to keep `curl` quiet, and somehow one needs to ignore the first 9 lines which are not JSON...

*Edit:*  As OP cannot seem to make it work without an explicit example, here is another copy and paste:

```
R> res <- system("curl -s -X POST --include \
    'https://community-sentiment.p.mashape.com/text/' -H \
    -X-Mashape-Key: \
    pVke3AAqHzmsh4xNdsKrPshYHQC1p1H78y0jsn2uwaEPcU1TnF' \ 
    -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json'  -d 'txt=Today is a good day'", \
    intern=TRUE)
R> jsonlite::fromJSON(res[-(1:9)])
$result
$result$confidence
[1] "96.7434"

$result$sentiment
[1] "Positive"


R>
```

You need to remove the `\` above and make it all one line.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I am getting curl not found error when I run as you said. I do have r curl installed! Also how can I add -d 'txt=Today is a good day' part in a variable? say text<-'Today is a good day' and use variable text in r syntax. Apologies in case it is very basic, I am new to R.

Comment: Please don't turn this into a basic R tutorial; it is not the place for it.  Look up "how to install curl" (which is an executable) and see `help(paste)` in R to combine strings.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I will go through the same.

Comment: Update: I have gone through by placing curl exe 64 bit for machine and placed in path C:\curl and placed the path in path variables via env variables. Curl not found error is gone but Still I get warning  had status 6. I will try to resolve the same and update.

Comment: Up: I have perfectly working Curl syntax here: curl -X POST -k -d "txt=Today is  a good day" https://community-sentiment.p.mashape.com/text/ -H "X-Mashape-Key: GVLOFKuxKcmshDybhhXfdQUi7eBDp1xXJvnjsn5d6XZeUCzQlw" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: application/json". But I can't make it as :res <- system("curl -s POST -k -d "txt=Today is  a good day" https://community-sentiment.p.mashape.com/text/ -H "X-Mashape-Key: GVLOFKuxKcmshDybhhXfdQUi7eBDp1xXJvnjsn5d6XZeUCzQlw" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: application/json"", intern=TRUE).

Comment: Dirk: Can you please help me with the complete syntax you entered in R console to get above result?

Comment: Exactly what you had,  but without backslashes.

Comment: Not sure: I used the same instructions as you said. Syntax: result<-system("curl -s POST --include 'https://community-sentiment.p.mashape.com/text/'  -H 'X-Mashape-Key: My_API_KEY'  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d 'txt=Today is a good day'",intern=TRUE) I am getting warning in R console saying: running curl ..(My complete syntax) had returned status 6.

Comment: If you need an extended tutorial, we can possibly agree on a rate.  Please stop requesting follow-ups an infinum here; I didn't agree to be your private consultant.

Comment: Apologies! Just was struck.

Comment: See above.  You need to edit it back into a single line.  Watch your single versus double quotes and make sure both are paired.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk and Apologies for inconvenience caused. I will figure it out where I am or my system going wrong and update with what  did to resolve. Thanks again for all help.